# Binding RadioButton to Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I have a `RadioButton` that is bound to a generic type... `TestObject<T>`

In this object, I have a property called Value which can be either 1 or 0. I have a property called `MyList` which is a `Dictionary<T,String>` which holds the following values:

```
   INT          String
    0            "This is the first option"
    1            "This is the second option"
```

What I am having trouble doing binding the `RadioButton` to `MyList`. Currently I have IsCheck ed bound to Value (with a converter to return true/false). My biggest issue is the dictionary and how to bind it to the `RadioButton` control so I can see 2 `RadioButton` options on the screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use a List of KeyValuePairs or Tuples instead of a Dictionary?

Then you could use the [ItemsControl](http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007041201.aspx), put the RadioButton in your DataTemplate and bind the ItemsSource to you List of KeyValuePairs.

Answer (score 0):

Try filling the radio buttons during runtime.

Here's an example using WPF:

```
    private RadioButton CreateRadioButton(RadioButton rb1, string content, Thickness margin, string name)
    {
        //private RadioButton CreateRadioButton(RadioButton rb1, string content, Thickness margin, string name)
        // We create the objects and then get their properties. We can easily fill a list.
        //MessageBox.Show(rb1.ToString());

        Type type1 = rb1.GetType();
        RadioButton instance = (RadioButton)Activator.CreateInstance(type1);

        //MessageBox.Show(instance.ToString()); // Should be the radiobutton type.
        PropertyInfo Content = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Content", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        PropertyInfo Margin = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Margin", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        PropertyInfo Name = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Name", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        // This is how we set properties in WPF via late-binding.
        this.SetProperty<RadioButton, String>(Content, instance, content);
        this.SetProperty<RadioButton, Thickness>(Margin, instance, margin);
        this.SetProperty<RadioButton, String>(Name, instance, name);

        return instance;
        //PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperties(rb1);
    }

    // Note: You are going to want to create a List<RadioButton>
```